# How to thaw soup without noodles going mushy

Tags: freezing, soup, noodles

I made a great vegetable soup in which I also put noodles and beans. Fresh, it was perfect. I froze most of it in small containers to thaw as I needed them. The problem is that when I thaw them, the noodles seem to get overcooked (they were "just-right") when the batch was fresh. I thaw the soup in a pot on the stove. I don't cook it exceptionally high, just hot enough to melt and warm the soup. Is there a better way to do it, so that the noodles (and to a lesser extent, the beans) won't get mushy when cooking to thaw?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop the cooking in my chicken and noodle soup?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17977/how-can-i-stop-the-cooking-in-my-chicken-and-noodle-soup). While the overcooking here happens at a different point of time, all the answers of the other question should be applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to this question: [How can I stop the cooking in my chicken and noodle soup?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17977/how-can-i-stop-the-cooking-in-my-chicken-and-noodle-soup) will help me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pasta will get softer and mushier with every heating and cooling cycle. Try a grain or rice instead.

Comment: I could, but I wanted *noodles!!* rumtscho posted a link to an answer which basically said that the soup to be frozen should stop cooking while the noodles are still a little firm. That way, they'll be fine on thaw/reheat.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is freezing the noodles and the soup or beans separately.

Instead of thawing the mix together, thaw separately. Use a frying pan with a bit of some oil on low heat to thaw the noodle. And just thaw the soup or beans in pot as you do usually.

Mix the noodle back into the soup / beans when ready.